# Indexing on Inner Join with Table Valued Function and OR statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, inner-join

I am inner joining a large table with a table valued function that returns a value to join on.
Unfortunately all my indexes are being bypassed resulting in a table scan on the large table. 
I have just used 1020 as the parameter here, but in reality this is a variable.

```
select t1.*
from [DS_DataAccess_XA_EMIR_TSR] t1 (nolock)
INNER JOIN SFTR_fn_UserAccess_GetLEIAccess(1020) t2
ON t1.[Trade Party 1 - Execution Agent ID] =  t2.LEI
OR t1.[Trade Party 2 - Execution Agent ID] = t2.LEI
```

I have separate indexes on both Trade Party fields setup. The function itself runs instantly. I have tried using cross apply as well but same results. See execution plan below, showing cost of query on table scan of large table:

[image]

Thank in advance!
Saul

Comment: `or` tends to kill the optimizer.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: Why `OR` and not `IN`?

Comment: On a different note, I'll just leave these here: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3), [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) & [Bad habits to kick : using dashes and spaces in entity names](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-dashes-and-spaces-in-entity-names)

Comment: It's just a case of displaying the data when either of those 2 fields match on the values returned from the table valued function.

Answer (score 2):

You only want data from the first table.  So, I would recommend using `exists` rather than `join`:

```
select t1.*
from [DS_DataAccess_XA_EMIR_TSR] t1
where exists (select 1
              from SFTR_fn_UserAccess_GetLEIAccess(1020) t2
              where t1.[Trade Party 1 - Execution Agent ID] =  t2.LEI
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from SFTR_fn_UserAccess_GetLEIAccess(1020) t2
              where t1.[Trade Party 2 - Execution Agent ID] = t2.LEI
             );
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried something similar to this (by using a subquery). It runs with varying results, but it seems to avoid the table scan on the large table, which is good news.

Answer (score 1):

The OR is preventing the engine to use an index, so I recommend you to split it in two different selects, and union them. So every select will be able to run with their corresponding index.

```
select t1.*
from [DS_DataAccess_XA_EMIR_TSR] t1 (nolock)
INNER JOIN SFTR_fn_UserAccess_GetLEIAccess(1020) t2 
           ON t1.[Trade Party 1 - Execution Agent ID] =  t2.LEI
UNION    
select t1.*
from [DS_DataAccess_XA_EMIR_TSR] t1 (nolock)
INNER JOIN SFTR_fn_UserAccess_GetLEIAccess(1020) t2 
           ON t1.[Trade Party 2 - Execution Agent ID] = t2.LEI
```

Comment: I guess this works well in most cases. Unfortunately my table valued function is referencing an XML field which cannot be used as an operand to the UNION.